# Passing and saving settings between FlipViewController from MainViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My FlipViewController has some setting in form of UISwitches for MainViewController. I am trying to set those settings (based on variables) when FlipViewController is loaded and save those settings when MainViewController is loaded back (from FlipView controller). Something is funky and i can't get it to work consistently.

It looks like when i call FlipViewController from MainViewController, FlipView is loaded before i can set the states of the switches in FlipView. How can i accomplish doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Vatsal

Function within MainViewController

```
// called when the user touches the info button
- (IBAction)showInfo
{
// create a new FlipsideViewController
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc]
                    initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];

controller.delegate = self; // set the delegate

// set the animation style to a horizontal flip
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

// show the flipside of the app
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

// set the controls on the flipside
[controller setSwitches]; // set each region's switch
//[controller setSelectedIndex:guessRows - 1]; // set number of choices

controller.wordsDatabase=self.wordsDatabase;

[controller release]; // release the controller FlipsideViewController
    } // end method showInfo
```

Function setting up switches in FlipView Controller (Called in MainView controller)

```
-(void) setSwitches
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like your `FlipSideViewController`'s `setSwtiches` method is called before you've assigned the controller a reference to the `wordsDatabase`.

ex:

```
[controller setSwitches];
controller.wordsDatabase=self.wordsDatabase;
```

should be:

```
controller.wordsDatabase=self.wordsDatabase;
[controller setSwitches];
```